# High PostgreSQL/PostGIS memory and disk usage when saving QGIS project

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, windows-10

Why would simply pressing the <kbd>Save</kbd> button in QGIS cause my local PostgreSQL instance to cause memory and disk usage to spike to "Not Responding" levels?  Seems to me like the PostgreSQL shouldn't even care about saving the project.  Are there any suggestions for improving the PostgreSQL DB performance?

**UPDATE**: Through some debugging in QGIS, I think I at least now understand why I am getting so much throughput to the DB on save.  QGIS is throwing dozens of errors like below (one for just about every layer in the project) in the PostGIS tab of the Log Messages Panel:

```
2020-09-02T09:19:51     WARNING    Error executing query: 
SELECT id,styleName,description FROM layer_styles 
WHERE f_table_catalog='<dbname>' 
AND f_table_schema='<shema_name>' 
AND f_table_name='<layer_name>' 
AND f_geometry_column='geom' ORDER BY useasdefault DESC, update_time DESC
2020-09-02T09:19:51     WARNING    No styles available on DB
```

I am not *intentionally* saving any layer symbology in the DB.  Any thoughts on what is causing this query to happen, and how I can remove it?

Background:
When I save my existing QGIS project (qgz) that has about 100 layers, all sourced from PostgreSQL/PostGIS, I frequently get a "Not Responding" message from QGIS.  While trying to debug the problem, I started watching the system resources and noticed that during these not responding times, the memory and disk i/o go crazy for the PostgreSQL instance, spiking the disk i/o to 100% (as high as 350 MB/s) and consuming 20% of the CPU.

I am running QGIS 3.12, PostgreSQL 9.5, and PostGIS 2.3 on a Windows 10 laptop with an Intel i5 CPU with 2 cores/4 processors and 12GB of RAM (physical memory) and a 1TB SSD hard drive.

Comment: Good question - Logically, if you are saving a Project, its simply saving the qgz file. Editing of data/layers obviously is transacting on the DB. So what is creating a transaction on the DB when you save the project?  Good question..... Im wondering if you could narrow it down to specific layers? Try saving your project as a new 'dummy' project, then start removing blocks of layers. This might find a troublesome layer, or narrow down if its the project itself causing issues.

Comment: You may want to monitor the statements sent to the server; for simplicity, run sth. like `watch -n 1 'PGPASSWORD=xxx psql -d <db> -U <superuser> -c "SELECT pid, usename, backend_start, state, query_start, wait_event_type, query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = '"'"'active'"'"' ORDER BY query_start"'` (note each call by watch runs in a different transaction), or use `pg_top` (`sudo apt install pgtop` & `pg_top -p <port> -U <superuser> -W -d <db> -I -c -s 1`). It's not uncommon for QGIS (or DB clients in general) to run dozens of queries in the background, doing integrity checks and so on.

Comment: On 100 layers, with potentially large base data relations behind them, that's likely taking a heavy toll. This might be something to keep an eye on and pass to the QGIS issue tracker to create awareness, if not already there. Sorry to assume Linux btw. ;-)

Comment: You may open too many connections in particular if you did not used `pg_service.conf` https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#service-connection-file Also what is the value of `SHOW max_connections;` when you run a query on your database?

Comment: Did you save your project within Postgres?  See here:  https://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/271-New-in-QGIS-3.2-Save-Project-to-PostgreSQL.html.  If so, I think that explains why you see a high Postgres load.  What I've read is that the qgz is saved as a blob in the database.

Comment: @jgm_GIS Negative, the project is saved to SSD disk.

Comment: @ThomasG77, I had not changed the default max_connections, but I did reset them to 5 based on your input.  Unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: This thread discusses blank styles in a postgres db.  http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Load-Style-from-database-dialog-is-blank-td5303285.html

Comment: Did you check the Log Message Panel especially the PostGIS tab?

Comment: @wondim, yes, the error message I posted in the question came from the PostGIS tab of the Log Messages Panel.

Comment: With a 100 layers it was always going to spike CPU/Disk usage. Did subsequent updates resolve this issue or have you found something troublesome in your layers? Feel free to post it as an answer.